# How do I force event reminders in Gnome Evolution?

Tags: gnome, evolution, calendar

I just missed an important appointment (that I will have to pay a penalty fee for) because I cannot set my own reminders on read-only calendars (managed by someone else) in Gnome Evolution and I have been relying on Gnome Evolution to keep me notified.

Is there an option to forcefully set a fixed reminder for all events regardless? or is there a way to set reminders for individual events regardless so that I don't miss any events?  I have gone to Preferences -> Reminders and *"Set default reminder"* setting but it doesn't work, I still do not get notified.  All calendars are also marked for reminder notification in the pane below

[image: GNOME Calendar - Reminders Preferences]

Version of Calendar is **3.36.4-0ubuntu1**

Comment: Can you put these events on your own personal calendar?

Comment: @DrewHowdenTech yes I can, it's a bit of a hassle but that is my current work-around.  What makes this untenable is that I have to be deliberate about it, which is error-prone if I forget to do it.